# Automatically generating pages from app data

Tags: django-cms

I am a novice to Django CMS and am wondering what is the best way to do the following.  I am running a Django CMS project together with a custom app that has an `Event` model for some (virtual) social events.  Ideally I would like the url `^events/<event_id>/` to map to the appropriate event page for any valid `Event` id value.  These event pages should look similar to my static pages, in particular using the same static placeholders and (ideally) inheriting from the same base template files.

What is the best way to achieve this?  It appears from the documentation that a plugin or apphooks would allow me to attach app data to a Django CMS page, but with that approach I would have to manually create a Django CMS page for each event.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually on SO you'd be asked to show what you've tried so far, but today is your lucky day .

Here's a **stub** of how you could achieve what you're describing. Regarding placeholders, you can find more info in the documentation [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/apphooks.html?highlight=placeholder#apphooks-and-placeholder-template-tags) and [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/placeholders.html?highlight=placeholder).

Good luck!

**`models.py`**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**`views.py`**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

class EventListView(ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = "events/listview.html"

class EventDetailView(ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = "events/detailview.html"
```

**`apphook_urls.py`**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', EventListView.as_view(), name='event-list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', EventDetailView.as_view(), name='event-detail'),
]
```

**`cms_apps.py`**

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool


class EventsAppHook(CMSApp):
    name = "Events"
    app_name = "events

    def get_urls(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return ["events.apphook_urls"]

apphook_pool.register(EventsAppHook)
```

Once everything is up and running, you attach your AppHook to a cms page of your choice and you should be good to go.

Comment: This works perfectly.  I had found a hack but this looks like the right way to do things.  Thank you so much!